# Put a pstricks cover at the beginning of a file without affecting the rest of it

Tags: compiling, pstricks, pdfpages

I have two files. One is a pstricks cover. The other is the interior of the book. They both are fine on their own.

I would like to put the code for pstricks cover on the first page of the pdf and compile the whole document. However, when I do that, it messes up the formatting of the interior of the book.

I have tried `\clearpage` and `\newpage` without success.

Basically, I want latex to pretend that there are two separate documents.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

create a new document

```
\documentclass[...]{article}% should have the same header as the original
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{...}% the same as in your text document
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=1-]{thetitle}% pdf document of the title
\includepdf[pages=1-]{thetext}% the main text doc
\end{document}
```

and you'll get a new one with the title and all text pages. If you create a four pages document for the title (the complete cover, the first 2 and last 2 pages), then do it this way:

```
\documentclass[...]{article}% should have the same header as the original
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{...}% the same as in your text document
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=1-2]{thetitle}% cover/back 
\includepdf[pages=1-]{thetext}% the main text doc
\includepdf[pages=3-4]{thetitle}% backcover
\end{document}
```